# Setting Session error in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I m trying to set Session in codeigniter. when a person try to login with email id and password.

1st)  using email id find his/her role. then return that result in session and  redirect to respective link. the code I typed below. Could you please solve this issue?

**Controller**

```
public function login_validation() {
        $this -> load -> library('form_validation');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required ');

        if ($this -> form_validation -> run()) {

            $this -> load -> model('model_database');
            $sessiondata['var_userrole'] = $this -> model_database -> login_session();

            $this -> session -> set_userdata($sessiondata);
            if ($var_userrole == admin) {

                redirect('welcome/admin');

            } else if ($var_userrole == staff) {

                redirect('welcome/staff');

            } else if ($var_userrole == student) {

                redirect('welcome/student');

            } else {

                redirect('welcome/login');

            }
```

**Model**

```
public function login_session() {
    $email = $this -> input -> post('email');
    $login_id = $this -> db -> query("SELECT var_userrole FROM tbl_login where var_email = '" . $email . "'");
    return  $login_id -> row_array();
}
```

Comment: and what is the issue ??

Comment: What is exactly the issue?!

Comment: @bipen and  Distinct  : I m a Beginner in CodeIgniter. Confused to set session after looking the user Guide. No error but not working ! I wanna know what I did on Controller session code is Correct or not? 

really appreciate your time. If code is not correct kindly show the right way.

Comment: we can't help you because we see no problems , what really is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

hi first of all $var_userrole is not defined anywhere which you are checking in if statements

**Controller**

```
public function login_validation() {
        $this -> load -> library('form_validation');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required ');

        if ($this -> form_validation -> run()) {

            $this -> load -> model('model_database');
            $var_userrole = $this -> model_database -> login_session();// was undefined 
            $sessiondata['var_userrole'] = $var_userrole

            $this -> session -> set_userdata($sessiondata);
            if ($var_userrole == admin) {

                redirect('welcome/admin');

            } else if ($var_userrole == staff) {

                redirect('welcome/staff');

            } else if ($var_userrole == student) {

                redirect('welcome/student');

            } else {

                redirect('welcome/login');

            }
```

**Model**

```
public function login_session() {
    $email = $this -> input -> post('email');
    $login_id = $this -> db -> query("SELECT var_userrole FROM tbl_login where var_email = '" . $email . "'");
      //$row =  $login_id -> row() // as object return $row->var_userrole;
      $row =  $login_id -> row_array();
    return $row['var_userrole']
}
```

well if you are developing something new for auth before that check some auth system in CI like ion_auth has group which you can mange and check user from which group its belong [Ion auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/)